# Stop subprocess.check_output to print on video

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm writing a python program which uses subprocess to send files via cURL. 
 It works, but for each file/zip it outputs the loading progress, time and other stuff which I don't want to be shown. 
 Does anyone know how to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL` or `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` to your `check_output` call

Comment: you're on the right track but that won't stop the standard output from being shown. In the subprocess call, you should add `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL` to send all standard output to the nether.

Comment: there are only `stderr` and `stdin` in the parameters

Comment: @User what do you mean?

Comment: scroll down to `check_output` https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

Comment: @User yes... I don't follow... the function takes `stderr` as a keyword argument? Look at the difference in output between `subprocess.check_output(['curl', 'stackoverflow.com'])` and `subprocess.check_output(['curl', 'stackoverflow.com'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)`

Comment: @User Ah I didn't realise that you are replying to @SyntaxVoid. Indeed `check_output` doesn't have `stdout` as an argument - that is what it returns!